# Why Nginx is redirecting my subdomain to the domain root?

Tags: nginx, amazon-route53

I am not a server admin so I am still learning. I am trying to create a subdomain for my website but every time when I am opening the subdomain it is pointing to domain root folder. I am trying to understand what am I doing wrong.

I have created the domain and subdomain using AWS Route 53 using this https://dev.to/arswaw/create-a-subdomain-in-amazon-route53-in-2-minutes-3hf0

So my path is like this

```
- var
  - www
    - html
      - webiste
      - subdomains
        - kiosk
```

Here is my website confing

```
server {
   root /var/www/html/website;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
   }
}
```

Here is my subdomain config

```
server {
   root /var/www/html/subdomains/kiosk;
   listen 80;
   server_name kiosk.example.com;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried private session? May some cache problems

Comment: @PurkhaloAlex How am I doing this?

Comment: i mean private session in your browser where is no cache. Also try to restart nginx and ensure that your changes has any impact.

Comment: @PurkhaloAlex I have restarted and I have opened it in incognito window and same thing

Comment: Maybe this happens because you are serving something on proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000 and its content override data from root.

Comment: @ changed to 9001 and same thing

Comment: Do you really need proxy pass attribute? what does it do in your case?

Comment: @PurkhaloAlex I am using it for DB

Comment: Are you sure that you have different content at `../subdomains/kios` and `.../website`?

Comment: @PurkhaloAlex 100% sure. Now I've deleted the files from `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` with `kiosk.example.com` and still opening the page. Do I need a separate EC2 instance for a subdomain?

Comment: @PurkhaloAlex in `kiosk.example.com` I have a record A pointing to the same EC2 instance ip as `example.com`

Comment: I don't think that problem in EC2 instance, but to insure you can test it locally adding a subdomain in /etc/hosts and testing it.